# swapping login/logout button in jquerymobile header

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left">主頁</a>
    <h1>header/h1>
    <a href="#page_login" data-role="button" id="button_login" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="false">login</a>
    <a href="#page_dashboard" data-role="button" id="button_logout" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="false">logout</a>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

So i have a login function, originally the logout is hidden when home page show, after the login success, the login button will be hidden and the logout button will be shown. But the problem is the logout button will drop to next row, how do i replace the position of login with logout button exactly the same?

Comment: How do you hide your login button ? Can you send your specific js code ?

Comment: $('#button_login').hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give login button class `ui-btn-right` statically, and then use the below code.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/veS5R/)**

```
// hide logout button initially
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
  $('#button_logout').toggle();
});

// hide login and show logout
$(document).on('click', '#button_login', function () {
  $('#button_logout').addClass('ui-btn-right').toggle();
  $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-right').toggle();
});

// hide logout and show login
$(document).on('click', '#button_logout', function () {
  $('#button_login').addClass('ui-btn-right').toggle();
  $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-right').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one button and change the text and class of the button.

Then in you code you can

```
$("#button").on ('click', function (e) {
    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "login" ) {
　　　　$( this ).removeClass( "login" );
       $( this ).addClass( "logout" );
       doLogin();
    } else {
　　　　$( this ).removeClass( "logout" );
       $( this ).addClass( "login" );
       doLogout();
    }
});
```